# How do I get standard output from QJSEngine in Qt 5.12?

Tags: qt, qjsengine

I enabled `ConsoleExtension` for debugging scripts by calling [`installExtensions`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#installExtensions). How can I capture the console output of QJSEngine?

Comment: `consloe.log()` ... ?

Comment: I know how I can print to stdout in JavaScript :). I don't know how I can read that from C++.

Comment: What do you mean by read that in C++ .. console logging id a debug tool ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the output of the script back into your C++ program, its best if you don't use the `ConsoleExtension` - instead expose an API to allow the script to call your implementation directly to "print to standard output".

Take for example what [Plasma ScriptEngine](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/blob/master/shell/scripting/scriptengine.cpp) does - it exposes a `print()` method on the `globalObject` that scripts can use to "print output". In Plasma that would be printed out from the plasmashell process and captured by various logging mechanisms, but you can do what you want with the input to your `print()` function. Your global object interface can even mimic `console.log()`.